# How to get the home directory of a login for a buffer in emacs using elisp?

Tags: shell, emacs, directory, environment-variables

I want a uniform way to get the home directory path. For both normal buffers and those loaded via tramp.
I am trying to make comint for shell use the history file in the login for a buffer. ie local file if normal buffers, and remote file for tramp buffers.

```lisp
    (add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'my-shell-mode-hook)
      (defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
        (setq comint-input-ring-file-name
              (substitute-in-file-name "~/.zsh_history"))
        ;; Ignore timestamps in history file.  Assumes that zsh
        ;; EXTENDED_HISTORY option is in use.
        (setq comint-input-ring-separator "\n: \\([0-9]+\\):\\([0-9]+\\);")
        (comint-read-input-ring t))
```

Comment: `(getenv "HOME")`?

Comment: `"~"` does not work?

Comment: Problem is here I get expanded environment in the remote machine. ie /home/username/.zsh_history , but comint tries to load that path from local machine. I think I would need a way to get the expanded home directory with tramp prefix preserved. ie /ssh:x@y:/home/user/.zsh_history. How to do that idk.

Comment: I found a similar question on reddit. [This piece of code](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5pziif/cd_to_home_directory_of_server_when_using_eshell/de9olb7/) might serve as inspiration - seems like it is able to figure out the remote home directory.

Comment: @legoscia Thanks !! , Was able to adapt it. You have helped a emacs n00b to write his first piece of elisp ...

Comment: Glad to hear! You can post your code as an answer to your question, to help future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using with-parsed-tramp-file-name macro, you can construct the file path of remote system. And then use "~" to access home folder.

```lisp
(defun my-shell-mode-hook ()
  (setq comint-input-ring-file-name
        (if (file-remote-p default-directory)
            (with-parsed-tramp-file-name default-directory nil
              (tramp-make-tramp-file-name
               (tramp-file-name-method v)
               (tramp-file-name-user v)
               (tramp-file-name-domain v)
               (tramp-file-name-host v)
               (tramp-file-name-port v)
               "~/.zsh_history"))
          "~/.zsh_history"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can simplify the above by just calling `tramp-make-tramp-file-name` with `tramp-dissect-file-name`, eg.

```
(tramp-make-tramp-file-name
  (tramp-dissect-file-name default-directory)
   "~/.zsh_history")
```

Using the first form it describes in the function's documentation.